# Como retornar dados da Activity chamada para aquela que a chamou?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

Vi vários exemplos de passar dados entre *Activity* de um *TextView* recebendo os dados de um *EditText*. Qual a melhor maneiro de fazer o caminho inverso, explico:

Tenho um leitor que lê um código de barras e mostra o resultado em um *TextView* gostaria de, ao fechar essa tela, a que a abriu receba esse resultado num *EditText* para assim gravá-lo no banco.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O mecanismo usado para receber valores de uma *Activity* após ela ser abandonada é, ao evocá-la, utilizar `startActivityForResult()` em vez de `startActivity()`.

Na primeira *Activity*:

```
static final int ACTIVITY_2_REQUEST = 1;

Intent i = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_2_REQUEST);
```

Na segunda *Activity*:

```
//Quando tiver o resultado pronto para ser devolvido à primeira activity

String resultado = seuTextView.getText().toString();
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("resultado",resultado);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
```

Para receber o valor faça o *override* do método `onActivityResult()` na primeira *Activity*:

```
@override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_2_REQUEST) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String resultado = data.getStringExtra("resultado");
            //Coloque no EditText
            seuEditText.setText(resultado);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu prefiro trabalhar em Android utilizando `Parcelable`, o que facilita e muito a passagem de objetos de qualquer tipo entre `Activitys`, além de ter retorno muito mais rápido, melhor processamento.

EX:

```
// ENVIO
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("nome", "Joao");


//RECEBENDO

Intent intent = getIntent();
String nome = intent.getStringExtra("nome");
```