# Passar dados entre Activity Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Eu sou novato em programação para android, e acabei de fazer meu primeiro app, mas estou com um problema, que é:

Meu jogo tem o menu inicial com o botão pra começar o jogo e a informação sobre o high score.

Começando o jogo vai para uma segunda tela onde o game começa e na tela mostra o score atual e o score a ser batido.

Nessa tela eu consegui salvar os dados com `SharedPreferences`, ou seja, nessa tela esta tudo ok, mas quero colocar a informação do `Highscore` dessa segunda tela na primeira, como fazer?

Na internet achei pra passar da primeira tela pra segunda, mas não encontrei da segunda tela para a primeira.

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso eu recomendaria que no método `onResume()` da primeira tela você buscasse os dados armazenados em Shared Preferences e os exibisse. Dessa forma, quando estiver na segunda tela e pressionar o botão "voltar" para retornar à primeira tela, o método `onResume()` da mesma será chamado e o Highscore será atualizado.

Na primeira tela você pode inclusive deixar a exibição do Highscore somente por conta do método `onResume()`, sem precisar exibi-lo no `onCreate()`. O ciclo de vida da activity vai fazer as coisas funcionarem corretamente, já que após o  `onCreate()` o `onResume()` é automaticamente chamado.

Comment: Essa pode ser a solução mais fácil mas não é a mais otimizada. Tendo em vista que cada vez que a activity chamar o `onResume()` irá ser buscado algo para atualizar o highscore sendo que não necessariamente haverá novos dados lá. O melhor seria iniciar a segunda activity usando o `startActivityForResult()` e deixar a consulta das preferences apenas no `onCreate()`.

Comment: Tem razão, não há por que não usar `startActivityForResult()`. A solução seria então assim: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73628/357](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73628/357)

Comment: Agora, não dá para escapar de buscar o Highscore na primeira Activity porque a ideia do AP é mostrá-lo também antes do jogo começar. Então o `startActivityForResult()` ser mais otimizado é questionável.

Comment: Ele vai ter que buscar na primeira activity sim.  Mas somente no onCreate(). A diferença em desempenho não será enorme,  mas entre trocas rápidas para outro App e de volta ao jogo,  não se paga o preço de outra busca no onResume(). Entre outros cenários.  Então,  sim, há um ganho,  mas não é algo relativamente grande.

Comment: Não é grande também porque a quantidade de informações acessada nas preferences é pouca.  Se fosse para um grande volume de dados,  a diferença em alternar apps rapidamente seria bem mais perceptível, por exemplo.