# Porque ao usar o intent abri um monte de janelas?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Tenho uma `ActivityA`, contém uma `ListView` e um `botão`, e tenho uma `ActivityB` que contem dois `EditText` e um botão.

Quando inicio `app` começa na `ActivityA` com lista vazia, ao apertar o botão executa o seguinte código

```
 Intent it = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
 startActivity(it);
```

Agora estou na `ActivityB` preencho os `EditTex` e aperto o botão que executa o seguinte código

```
   String texto = editTexto.getText().toString();
   double numero = Double.parseDouble(editnumero.getText().toString());


        Intent it = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        it.putExtra("texto", texto);
        it.putExtra("numero", numero);
        startActivity(it);
```

Assim estou na `ActivityA`, dentro do `onCreate` segue o código

```
     Intent it  = getIntent();
     texto = it.getStringExtra("texto");
     numero = it.getDoubleExtra("numero", -1);

        if(texto != null)
     //List<Carro> carro = new ArrayLis<Carro>(); variável global
        carro.add( new Desejo(texto,numero));
        carroAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<Carro>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,carro );
        listaCarro.setAdapter(carroAdapter);
    }
```

Ok, funciona, mas ao clicar novamente no botão vou para `ActivityB`, digito os valores e clico no botão, vou para `ActivityA`. o que tinha adicionado antes sumiu ficando acionado na lista o ultimo dado.
Mas percebi ele abriu outra janela.

Como resolver esse problema de janelas e se o valor foi adicionado à lista mesmo que abriu em outra janela era para ter a lista completa?

Comment: Na forma como está formulada, a pergunta é duplicata. No entanto, tendo em conta o que pretende fazer melhor seria usar `startActivityForResult()` para lançar a Activity B. Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73628/2541) e na documentação [Como obter resultados de uma atividade](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: @ramaral quando você escreve lançar Activity B, você está querendo dizer ir A para B, ou do B para A

Comment: Ir de A para B.