# Como pegar valores da Intent da ActivitB e passar para ActivityA numa Lista?

Tags: android, android-intent

Tenho uma `ActivityA` que é a principal, contém uma `ListView` e um `botão`, e tenho uma `ActivityB` que contem dois `EditText` e um botão.

Quando inicio `app` começa na `ActivityA` com lista vazia, ao apertar o botão executa o seguinte código

```
 Intent it = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
 startActivity(it);
```

Agora estou na `ActivityB` preencho os `EditTex` e aperto o botão que executa o seguinte código

```
   String texto = editTexto.getText().toString();
   double numero = Double.parseDouble(editnumero.getText().toString());


        Intent it = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        it.putExtra("texto", texto);
        it.putExtra("numero", numero);
        startActivity(it);
```

Assim estou na `ActivityA`, dentro do `onCreate` segue o código

```
     Intent it  = getIntent();
     texto = it.getStringExtra("texto");
     numero = it.getDoubleExtra("numero", -1);

        if(texto != null)
     //List<Carro> carro = new ArrayLis<Carro>(); variável global
        carro.add( new Desejo(texto,numero));
        carroAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<Carro>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,carro );
        listaCarro.setAdapter(carroAdapter);
    }
```

Ok, funciona, mas ao clicar novamente no botão vou para `ActivityB`, digito os valores e clico no botão, vou para `ActivityA`. o que tinha adicionado antes sumiu ficando acionado na lista o ultimo dado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando uma Activity é trazida para *foreground* um de 3 métodos é chamado e recebe o *intent* que originou esse facto:

- `onCreate()` - Quando é criada uma nova instância da Activity.
- `onNewIntent()` - Quando existe uma instância da Activity e no AndroidManifest.xml o atributo `launchMode` foi declarado como `"singleTop"` ou o intent contém as *flags* `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` e `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` "setadas".
- `onActivityResult()`- Quando a *activity* lança outra, através de `startActivityForResult()`, e essa é terminada.

Para que a ActivityA mantenha os seus dados e a eles sejam adicionados dados provenientes da ActivityB, tem de garantir que o *intent* usado na ActivityB, para chamar a ActivityA, não crie outra instância de ActivityA.
Para isso use, na declaração da activity no AndroidManifest.xml, o atributo

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

ou crie o *intent* desta forma

```
Intent it = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
it.putExtra("texto", texto);
it.putExtra("numero", numero);
it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(it);
```

Qualquer que seja a forma adoptada, quando a ActivityA passar para *foreground*, o método que é chamado é `onNewIntent()`.
Assim, deve passar o código que actualiza a ListView do `onCreate()` para ele.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    String texto = intent.getStringExtra("texto");
    String numero = intent.getDoubleExtra("numero", -1);

    if(texto != null)
    carro.add( new Desejo(texto,numero));
    carroAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<Carro>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,carro );
    listaCarro.setAdapter(carroAdapter);
}
```

Normalmente a abordagem usada em casos como este - usar uma segunda activity para obter dados para a primeira - é lançar a segunda activity com [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) e receber os dados(intent) no método [onActivityResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)).
Para um exemplo veja [Como retornar dados da Activity chamada para aquela que a chamou?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73570/como-retornar-dados-da-activity-chamada-para-aquela-que-a-chamou/73628#73628).