# Pegar data do intent activity

Tags: android

Estou setando as informações assim em meu intent, porém preciso recuperar caso volte para tela. como fazer ?

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("OPCIONAIS", (Serializable) listaOpcionais);
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
```

Preciso recuperar e colocar na variável `listaOpcionais`. Preciso fazer isto para que assim que chegar na tela, ele recarregue os opcionais que estão na memoria.

O método que preciso pegar os dados é este:

```
@AfterViews
public void init(Intent data) {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    comida = (Comida) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(COMIDA);
    tamanho = (Tamanho) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(TAMANHO);
    restaurante = (Restaurante) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(RESTAURANTE);

    listaOpcionais = data.getStringExtra("resultado");
    configurarOpcionais();
}
```

Porém na linha `listaOpcionais = data.getStringExtra("resultado");` ele está esperando um array e não uma string

Comment: A pergunta não está muito clara. Veja se é isto o que procura [Como retornar dados da Activity chamada para aquela que a chamou?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73570/2541)

Comment: @ramaral é exatamente isto, porém o meu esta no scope do init, como fazer?

Comment: Vi que no exemplo  ele ta no método onActivityResult, preciso recuperar no init

Comment: @ramaral atualizei minha pergunta